# Changing Color of text when color is selected from combo box

Tags: c++, windows, combobox, mfc, colorbox

I would like to change the text color of the text present in `IDC_EDIT1` box when a new color is selected from the combo box. But it is now working,
`OnCbnSelchangeComboColorBox` :- Event Handler for Combo Box
`m_Combo_Box` :- Variable name for combo box.
`m_text` :- Variable name for `IDC_EDIT1`.

[image]

```cpp
void CFontFormatter::OnCbnSelchangeComboColorBox()
{
    int comboBoxSelectedItem = m_Combo_Box.GetCurSel();
    if (comboBoxSelectedItem != LB_ERR) {
        CString selectedColorText;
        m_Combo_Box.GetLBText(comboBoxSelectedItem, selectedColorText);
        if (selectedColorText == _T("Red"))
            fontColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        else if (selectedColorText == _T("Green"))
            fontColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        else if (selectedColorText == _T("Blue"))
            fontColor = RGB(0, 0, 255);
        CWnd* pEditControl = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
        if (pEditControl)
        {
            CDC* pDC = m_editText.GetDC();
            pDC->SetTextColor(fontColor);
            pEditControl->Invalidate();
            pEditControl->UpdateWindow();
        }
        m_text.SetString(selectedColorText);
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
}
```

I have Tried through `CWnd*` and `CDC*`.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but I believe you want this: [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit).

Comment: Totally off topic and just asking out of curiosity: why do you put a `-` after the `:` in the label `Sample text :-`? it should be just `Sample text:`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one resource https://www.equestionanswers.com/vcpp/background-color-edit-static.php). They provide some code:

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
{
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,255));
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,230,0));
    return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,230,0));
}
```